# Transformerless Realtime Clock Issue

Tags: pic, clock, rtc, transformerless

[image: Transformerless Real Time Clock Issue]
I have an issue with designing a Real Time Clock by using Transformerless power supply. I don't use RTC IC but I use Microchip PIC instead and 32kHz clock. I use battery of 3.3V for backup supply. The problem is when I cut off the AC power, then PIC is reset. However when I tested with cutting off DC supply no reset occur. My project is working on 5V powering and 12V for controlling a relay. Overall current is about 20mA when I test it with DC supply, so in transformerless power supply, I use X-rate cap 0.47uF in Full Bridge configuration. Could you please give me any idea what my problem is? Thanks,

Comment: Please provide a schematic. As complete a schematic as you can.

Comment: Hello, here it is.

Comment: A few questions. D5 is a 9V Zener diode. Are you sure you're getting 12V there? What's the reset voltage on the PIC set to? Is the PIC responsible for flipping the relay when the battery voltage is gone?

Comment: Oh, 1- sorry I used 12V zener instead of 9V here on my hardware anyway. 2- Reset voltage is VDD (5V if there is an AC supply and 3.3V if AC is cut off. 3-  "PIC responsible for flipping the relay when the battery voltage is gone", do you refer to sofware? no I just test it first with delay command.

Comment: What pic are you using? The pic16f675 is not a valid part. Also at what clock speed are you running the processor?

Comment: Thank you, sorry I named PIC wrong but it is 12F675 instead and the oscillator is 4MHz.